# At the time, I was leaving/was about to leave/was going to leave my friend's house. - do they mean the same?

Tags: meaning, modal-verbs

Wife: You came home pretty late last night. What were you doing? I called you at 10.

**Example 1**

> Husband: At the time, I was leaving my friend's house.

**Example 2**

> Husband: At the time, I was going to leave my friend's house.

**Example 3**

> Husband: At the time, I was about to leave my friend's house.

Are all three the same meaning?

Do all of them mean I was in the process of leaving the house?

I know "was going to" is often used when something was supposed to happen but got canceled.

Does Example 2 imply something happened and I cancelled the action of leaving?

Answer (score 1):

(1) He was in the process of leaving.

(2) He was intending to leave. (Without further information, it doesn't imply that he changed his mind.)

(3) He was getting ready to leave.

Comment: I would say 1) he was stepping out of the door